# How to check control keys within string by php

Tags: php

I have string as below:

- abccdef\x7f
  (notice that the '\x7f' is Del key on keyboard)
  I want to check if the above string has control key or not ?

Control keys include: Del, Tab, Esc, F1 ~ F12, Shift,....

Please help me the solution, I am using PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There,

You can use the `php`s [`ctype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) extension there are many functions to do your stuff.

For Exmaple you can use [ctype_print()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php) function which Checks all chars if there printable as cntrl chars aren't printable it should help you.

```php
$x = "asbahsdb\x7f";
$y = "JustText";

var_dump(
  ctype_print($x), // False
  ctype_print($y)  // True
);
```

Comment: I have just checked it, but it only work with double quote, single quote is not work :D

Comment: @huepham Hey, its php man You cant do much escaping with single quote check this out https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: @huepham Okay why dont you just simply add a bit of your code in the example, its much easier to understand and fast.

Comment: @huepham If you have literally “backslash ex 7” in your text, those are all normal characters and not a delete key…

Comment: I tried and it works ok as below thanks,
ctype_print(print($x)).
Thanks